# Get URI from ContentResolver.query()

Tags: android, uri, android-contentprovider, android-contentresolver

I am querying the `Images` table to get all pictures in the `MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI` directory.

See the following query:

```
String[] what = new String[]{ MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATE_TAKEN,
            MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns._ID,
            MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.MIME_TYPE,
            MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA };

String where = MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE + "='image/jpeg'" +
            " OR " + MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE + "='image/png’";

Cursor cursor = getContext().getContentResolver()
                    .query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, 
                            what,
                            where,
                            null,
                            MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATE_TAKEN + " DESC”);
```

Now, I’d like to have an Uri pointing to each of the result.
This is what I am doing right now:

```
int dataIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA);
String path = cursor.getString(dataIndex);
final Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(path));
```

E.g., I take the path from the `DATA` column, create a file and use `Uri.fromFile`. I have two questions.

1. Is this guaranteed to work? Is the query above guaranteed to return paths in the data column? It works for all the pictures in my phone: `path` is always a path, like `/storage/0/whatever.jpg`, and `uri.toString()` is the same but with the file scheme. Still, pictures can very well be defined by content:// uris, but I fail to see how (and if) these are represented in the images table.
2. If not, what should I expect in the `DATA` column, and how to get an Uri from it?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

> Is the query above guaranteed to return paths in the data column?

It should return something. That "something" may not be usable. For example, the image might be on removable storage, and you cannot access it directly.

> how to get an Uri from it?

You don't. You construct a `Uri` from the `_ID`:

```
Uri imageUri=
  ContentUris
    .withAppendedId(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
       cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns._ID)));
```

Comment: Interesting, thank you. Just one thing about the “may not be usable part”. As I understand, you mean that I can’t call new File(path) on these. But if I build an Uri as you said, will they be accessible through ContentResolver.open() ?

Comment: Rewording, is the Uri built with ContentUri s safe (i.e. works even in edge cases like images in removable storage) or should I add a check somewhere?

Comment: @mvai: So long as you have `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`, you should be OK. Though, testing is recommended. :-) I have done more work with videos than still photos, and it seems to be fine there. The worst-case outcome is just what you have with the `File` approach: no access.